# PHP cURL: could not resolve host (over VPN)

Tags: php, macos, curl, dns, vpn

I work remotely and can access internal servers via VPN. When my VPN connection is established, I can reach my webserver via curl:

```
curl http://sub.mydomain.com
```

I can also reach the webserver in a browser by going to `http://sub.mydomain.com`. So this does not seem to be a DNS issue with the webserver itself.

When developing my Laravel 4.2 application (PHP 5.6) served locally via Apache, however, php's `curl_exec` fails to resolve the host. Oddly, php's `gethostbyname($hostname)` correctly resolves the host. I have tried forcing IPv4 as I have read IPv6 can result in failures of this type with no success.

```
// works
$ip = gethostbyname($hostname);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://$ip/path");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_exec($ch);

// does NOT work
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://$hostname/path");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_exec($ch);
```

This leaves me at a loss. I don't understand how PHP curl handles DNS resolution (clearly not with `gethostbyname`). I also don't understand exactly how DNS lookups on private networks work in the first place. So I really don't know where to look to get PHP curl to resolve my private hosts.

Comment: > So this does not seem to be a DNS issue with the webserver itself.

The DNS seen by your webserver is not the same as the DNS seen on your client. Connections into a datacentre are not the same connections out of a datacentre. http://$ip/ might be a completely different website from http://$hostname/ (an IP address can have multiple virtual hosts, a virtual host can span multiple ip addresses). Curl can report an issue with DNS when the problem lies elsewhere. Question is confused and lacking in relevant detail. Try testing it from the command line on the server.

Comment: I guess I was not clear, but the browser test, command line curl, and PHP code were all run on a client machine. All worked except PHP curl, so this is not an issue of incoming vs outgoing connections. See my answer for details on the actual issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Command line `curl` resolved the host. Browser resolved the host. Only PHP curl failed to resolve it.

Ultimately, the issue came down to the curl configuration. I installed PHP with homebrew and as a dependency it installed `curl-openssl` to be used by PHP. This install of curl is configured by the brew formula to use `c-ares` for domain name resolution. I don't know how `c-ares` works, but this VPN DNS is apparently an edge case it does not handle correctly on OS X (perhaps due to OS X doing a lousy job of keeping `/etc/resolv.conf` up to date).

`/usr/bin/curl` on the other hand was configured to use the native OS X resolver. This is the same resolver used by PHP's `gethostbyname` and the web browser, which explains why both of those work as expected.

```
$ brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies curl-openssl
```

This resolved my issue by dumping this "broken" curl installation. I am not sure how the fallback mechanism works, but I believe PHP is now using `/usr/bin/curl` since I have no other installations of `curl` (that I know about) and the `curl` version listed in `phpinfo()` now matches `/usr/bin/curl` when before it did not.

Comment: Thank you so much ! You just save my day !

Comment: Given the number of people who are newly working from home due to covid-19 (likely over VPN connections), I hope this answer helps more!